# Interpolating from coarse to finer resolution grid

Tags: r

I am attempting to interpolate temperatures (Tas) from a coarse grid (2.5° x 2.5°) to a finer resolution grid (0.5° x 0.5°). My data takes the form:

```
COARSE = matrix(c(rep(seq(-180, -170, by = 2.5), times = 5), 
            rep(seq(40, 50, by = 2.5), each = 5), 
            rep(seq(6, 10, by = 1), times = 5)),
            nrow = 25, ncol = 3)
colnames(COARSE) = c("Lon", "Lat", "Tas")

FINE = matrix(c(rep(seq(-180, -170.5, by = 0.5), times = 20), 
              rep(seq(40, 49.5, by = 0.5), each = 20), 
            rep(seq(5, 9, by = 1), times = 80)),
            nrow = 400, ncol = 3)
colnames(FINE) = c("Lon", "Lat", "Tas")
```

The output should be a matrix with the Lon and Lat of the finer grid in the first two columns, and then the third column should represent the coarse grid Tas values interpolated onto the finer grid.

I have attempted using the bilinear function in the Akima package but I can't understand how this works well enough to adapt it to my situation. Surely the above example is really straightforward to interpolate? I have searched for many examples in the past few days and am stumped. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your data is a three-column matrix of x,y,z values, whereas all the `akima` package functions work with a vector of x, a vector of y, and a matrix of z.

Comment: `akima::interpp(COARSE[,1], COARSE[,2], COARSE[,3], FINE[,1], FINE[,2])`?

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution, but unfortunately this returns: 

Error in `[.data.frame`(x@data, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Thank you @ Rui Barradas - I got this to work in the end - my R studio was playing up for a while

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the interpolation like this, where the 2-D interpolation `interp2` in package `pracma` is used:

```
library(pracma)
FINE[,3] <- interp2(unique(COARSE[,1]),
                    unique(COARSE[,2]),
                    matrix(COARSE[,3],nrow = length(unique(COARSE[,1]))),
                    unique(FINE[,1]),
                    unique(FINE[,2]))
```

such that

```
> head(FINE,20)
         Lon Lat Tas
 [1,] -180.0  40 6.0
 [2,] -179.5  40 6.2
 [3,] -179.0  40 6.4
 [4,] -178.5  40 6.6
 [5,] -178.0  40 6.8
 [6,] -177.5  40 7.0
 [7,] -177.0  40 7.2
 [8,] -176.5  40 7.4
 [9,] -176.0  40 7.6
[10,] -175.5  40 7.8
[11,] -175.0  40 8.0
[12,] -174.5  40 8.2
[13,] -174.0  40 8.4
[14,] -173.5  40 8.6
[15,] -173.0  40 8.8
[16,] -172.5  40 9.0
[17,] -172.0  40 9.2
[18,] -171.5  40 9.4
[19,] -171.0  40 9.6
[20,] -170.5  40 9.8
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomaslsCoding but for me this gives the following:

Error in interp2(unique(COARSE[, 1]), unique(COARSE[, 2]), matrix(COARSE[,  : 
  Required: 'length(x) = ncol(Z)' and 'length(y) = nrow(Z)'.

Comment: @DJ-AFC are you using the data in your post or other data? No problem for me when with you posted data

Comment: I'm using different data - much larger datasets. But identical structure - hence why I thought it should translate perfectly.

Comment: @DJ-AFC Did you try my code on the data in this post?

Comment: I did and unfortunately the same error came up. I will reload R and try again as it has been behaving slightly strangely today!

Comment: @DJ-AFC yes, clean up your R environment and try it again

Comment: Aha - that did the trick when I cleaned up and reloaded. Many thanks! Unfortunately it still doesn't work with the larger datasets. I would reproduce those here but am not sure how to do so.